# make: ifort: Command not found?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04, gfortran

I am trying to install [sann](https://github.com/newtonjoo/sann) package. Based on the creator instructions I entered into the `src` folder and executed `make` command but end up with the following error,

```
dinesh@dinesh7k:~/Documents/tools/MIonSite-master/standardalone_MIonSite/sann-master/src$ make
ifort -c -O3 -openmp -o params.o params.f90
make: ifort: Command not found
Makefile:32: recipe for target 'params.o' failed
make: *** [params.o] Error 127
```

I have already installed `gfortran` in my computer (ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64 bit version)

```
dinesh@dinesh7k:~/Documents/tools/MIonSite-master/standardalone_MIonSite/sann-master/src$ dpkg -L gfortran
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/bin/gfortran
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gfortran
/usr/share/doc/gfortran
/usr/share/man/man1/gfortran.1.gz
```

But, I could not fix thiss issue, please help me to fix this issue,
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/newtonjoo/sann/tree/master/src) it looks like there are two Makefiles:

- `Makefile.intel` that contains the make commands assuming `ifort`
- `Makefile.gfortran` that contains the commands assuming `gfortran`.

The main Makefile is just a symlink to `Makefile.intel`. By changing that link to point to `Makefile.gfortran`, you should be able to use the gfortran compiler.

So run:

```
rm Makefile
ln -s Makefile.gfortran Makefile
```

... and follow the rest of the instructions:

```
make
make install
```